# Is clip and ship possible with ArcGIS Server map service?

Tags: arcgis-server, map-service, geoprocessing-service, feature-service

Is clip and ship possible with a map service?

Following the [tutorial](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Clip_and_ship/005700000073000000/), it appears you can publish a clip and ship GP service, but it will only work with Arc Map layers (SDE, FGDB layer, etc...) and not a Map/Feature Service. Is that correct?

We'd like to be able  to publish a clip and ship that allowes users to extract data from a web map.

If this is possible, are there any configuration examples?

Not finding any on Esri web site.

Comment: You can do just about *anything* in a GP service or SOE.   However, you'd need to code it, not just configure it.

Answer (score 4):

As Vince pointed out in a comment - you could theoretically write code to clip a map/feature service. But that would probably be a lot of custom work. You wouldnt as much be extending the Clip and Ship tool as you'd be writing a custom extraction of JSON from map services.

Generally the clip and ship work flow is comprised of 2 services: GP + Map. They both reference the same data. The map service (which you build a webmap off of) is so the user knows what data they're working with and in what area (visualized) and the GP service is there to provide the extraction.

The tutorial talked about is this one: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Clip_and_ship/005700000073000000/